# How reset date milliseconds using pure js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm using EJS to compare the current date and a event date (data from database).

```
if (event[i].date >= new Date()) {
 render this html
}
```

The problem is that event[i].date always have the milliseconds 0, example:

`Fri Jan 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)`

And when i try to get the new Date(), now for example, this will happen:

`Fri Jan 23 2015 01:28:42 GMT-0200 (BRST)`

So, new Date() is greater then event[i].date, this will make the html not render..

How can i set to 0 the milliseconds of new Date()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as the following

```
var a = new Date();
a.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```